# True/False error for stacked bar plots with error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a working stacked bar plot which I make using the following code:

```
stackedCE_avg <- ggplot() + 
geom_bar(data = Com_avgCE_stdev, stat = "identity", size = 0.25, colour ="black", width =0.5, aes(x=x, y= value, fill=variable)) + 
#geom_errorbar(aes(x = x, ymin = sd_neg, ymax = sd_pos), width=0.1) +
theme_bw() +
ylab("Percent") + 
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100)) +
theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position ="top", legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.text = element_text(size = 8), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8), strip.text = element_text(size = 8), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey77", "grey40")) +
facet_grid(Reactor ~ Tag, scales="free")
```

The moment I take off the `#` in my `geom_errorbar` and try to add that layer if I get the following message

> Error in if (empty(data)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I'm not exactly sure why this one line is not working to add the error bars and I'm not sure what it means by missing values. I thought perhaps it was the NA's in my data frame so I changed them all to 0's. This didn't fix the problem. Any suggestions on how to fixed the error is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDITS: the error bars finally showed up but they were not in the right positions.  I ended up figuring out how to generate the right positions by adding the values of the bottom columns to the values of the stop columns and then calculation the position of the min and ymax (it wasn't pretty). Now the error bars don't match the colors of the stacked columns. This is my new code:

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.65)
stackedCE_avg <- ggplot() + 
geom_bar(data = Com_avgCE_stdev, stat = "identity", size = 0.25, colour = "black", width =0.5, aes(x=x, y= value, fill=variable)) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey77", "grey40")) +
geom_errorbar(aes(x = x, ymin = sd_neg, ymax = sd_pos, color = variable), width=0.25, data = Com_avgCE_stdev, position = "dodge") +
theme_bw() +
ylab("Percent") + 
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100)) +
theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position ="top", legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.text = element_text(size = 8), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8), strip.text = element_text(size = 8), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
facet_grid(Reactor ~ Tag, scales="free")
```

The only thing I want to do is get the colors to match the colors I have designated for the fill color.

Comment: Try with `geom_errorbar(aes(x = x, ymin = sd_neg, ymax = sd_pos), width=0.1, data=Com_avgCE_stdev)`

Comment: Thanks, Marco! Doing what you suggested made those error bars appear. Now to figure out how to adjust their heights. It seems like the error bars are graphed right on the position I have designed without taking into consideration that the data is stacked.

Comment: Can you share a part of your dataset ? It would be easier to help you. You can paste in your question the output of `dput(Com_avgCE_stdev)` or `dput(Com_avgCE_stdev[1:25,])`